# creating tuple with repeating elements

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to create tuple of following kind:

```
('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 3)
```

from arrays:

`A = ['a','b']` and numbers 0 through 3.

What is good pythonic representation as I am ending with a real for loop here.

Comment: `[ (a,n) for n in num  for a in A ]` where num is range(0,3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`.

```
from itertools import product

tuples = list(product(['a', 'b'], [0, 1, 2, 3]))
print(tuples) # [('a', 0), ('a', 1), ..., ('b', 0), ('b', 1), ...]
```

If you need them in the exact order you originally specified, then:

```
tuples = [(let, n) for n, let in product([0, 1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'])]
```

If your comment that "I am ending with a real for loop here" means you ultimately just want to iterate over these elements, then:

```
for n, let in product([0, 1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']):
    tup = (let, n) # possibly unnecessary, depending on what you're doing
    ''' your code here '''
```

Answer (score 4):

You could opt for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the Cartesian product you're looking for. If the element order isn't of significance, then we have

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(A, range(4)))
[('a', 0),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 2),
 ('a', 3),
 ('b', 0),
 ('b', 1),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 3)]
```

If you need that *particular* order,

```
>>> list(tuple(reversed(x)) for x in product(range(4), A))
[('a', 0),
 ('b', 0),
 ('a', 1),
 ('b', 1),
 ('a', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('a', 3),
 ('b', 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
L = range(0, 4)
K = ['a', 'b']

L3 = [(i, j) for i in K for j in L]
print(L3)
```

**OUTPUT**
`[('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 0), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)]`

If you wish to use list comprehension... other answers are correct as well

Answer (score -2):

Use list comprehension

```
>>> [(a,n) for a in list1 for n in range(4)]
[('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 0), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

If order matters:

```
>>> [(a,n) for n in range(4) for a in list1]
[('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 3)]
```